# Why do the Pokemon always have three pawprints?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was told in pokemon go, the pawprints near the pokemon represent the distance away from me, but as I move around I run into pokemon and all of the distance markers stay at 3 paw prints, never lowering to 2 or 1. What's going on?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a [glitch currently with the game](https://twitter.com/PoGoServer/status/754827110443782144).

It will likely be fixed soon.

Comment: Whew. I walked all over the place last night trying to figure out what the "nearby" system was trying to tell me and it made **no sense**. I'm glad i'm not stupid - it's just broken. +1

Comment: It's probably not a glitch though, it seems to me that it's a coping mechanism to solve the extreme load Niantic servers are under at the moment.

Comment: @Spork It is not expected or intended behavior, thus it is a glitch.

Comment: @Spork it's unlikely that this feature would. Require additional server communication. The client would get the pokemons location from the server and could then calculate if it's three two or one away

Comment: Note that this is an unofficial Twitter account. There's no official statement regarding this issue.

Comment: Aequitas: I don't see how it could be a client side bug. It suddenly appeared in my game despite me not updating the client-side app, unless the app updates itself when it opens.

Answer (score 1):

Until the bug is fixed you can use a web service like https://pokevision.com/ which shows you the exact position if Pokémon near your position.