# Why isn't the 'Nearby Pokemon' menu showing any distance footsteps?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've logged in and out, restarted my phone, updated, but the Pokemon footsteps indicating whats nearby wont show up.

The Pokemon still appear in the menu, but I cannot click to select them, nor does it show their distance from me with the footsteps.

What is going on?

Comment: The footsteps were removed in the latest version of Pokemon Go (for whatever reason). It's by design. You can't reliably track them anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do the Pokemon always have three pawprints?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275591/why-do-the-pokemon-always-have-three-pawprints)

Comment: Note: The dupe says three pawprints, but they've since updated the game to be zero pawprints.  The source is the same: it's busted.

Comment: All the comments above are correct... Niantic removed them until they can get tracking in a usable, working state, as stated in [articles such as this](http://kotaku.com/thats-one-way-to-fix-pokemon-gos-three-step-glitch-1784589719). So, the 'Nearby' box does not show footprints, **and** it does not let you click on them to even tell you if you are headed in the right direction anymore. It's basically useless in its current state, since it doesn't help you track direction/distance anymore.

Comment: @Frank While the source of the problem is essentially the same, the questions here are different (why are there 3 pawprints vs why are there *no* pawprints). Not a dupe IMO.

Comment: @fredley Only from the most pedantic point of view.  Do we really need or want two questions asking about the same mechanic being broken?

Comment: @Frank If they present different problems from a player perspective, then yes.

Answer (score 4):

In the most recent update, Niantic removed the tracking functionality (that wasn't even working prior to the update).

Previously, three footsteps would show for every Pokémon, and they wouldn't track, now the UI matches the functionality available.

The feature was removed due to the computational load on Niantic's servers.